# Median and quantile values in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my dataframe I have an age column. The total number of rows are approx 77 billion. I want to calculate the quantile values of that column using PySpark. I have some code but the computation time is huge (maybe my process is very bad).

Is there any good way to improve this?

Dataframe example:

```
id       age
1         18
2         32
3         54
4         63
5         42
6         23
```

What I have done so far:

```
#Summary stats
df.describe('age').show()

#For Quantile values
x5 = df.approxQuantile("age", [0.5], 0)
x25 = df.approxQuantile("age", [0.25], 0)
x75 = df.approxQuantile("age", [0.75], 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first improvment to do would be to do all the quantile calculations at the same time:

```
quantiles = df.approxQuantile("age", [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], 0)
```

Also, note that you use the exact calculation of the quantiles. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile) we can see that (emphasis added by me):

> relativeError – The relative target precision to achieve (>= 0). If set to zero, the **exact quantiles are computed, which could be very expensive**. Note that values greater than 1 are accepted but give the same result as 1.

Since you have a very large dataframe I expect that some error is acceptable in these calculations, but it will be a trade-off between speed and precision (although anything more than 0 could have a significant speed improvement).

Comment: This special Quantiles would be called Quartiles I assume...